# How to fix 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll after unison scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, datagridview

I have two datagriviews, the requirements is that both datagriviews need to scroll in unison to allow the user to be able to see the ‘Input’. To clarify:

1. I will create a new file by browsing for the original file,
2. When it loads (grid1) it loads with one grid being empty (grid2) so that I'm able to input from grid2.

All the menotined above it is working fine as I can save and edit the file. I created the unison scrolling but it only scrolls one row and throws an error below,

> Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Scrolling code,

```
private void Gridview1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow _row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < Gridview1.Columns.Count; n++)
        {
            Gridview1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(Gridview1_Scroll);  //it throws an error here.
        }
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow _roww in Gridview2.Rows)
    {
        for (int nn = 0; nn < Gridview2.Columns.Count; nn++)
        {
            Gridview2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Gridview1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you adding the event handler so many times to `GridView1.Scroll` ??
`Gridview1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(Gridview1_Scroll);  //it throws an error here.`

Comment: You're subscribing to that event rows x columns times and then when fired you do this again, so the number of subscriptions will increase exponentially as the event fires. No wonder you run out of memory! What are you trying to do? You should only need a single subscription!

Comment: So how must i tackle this problem which will lead to solution?

Answer (score 0):

Move this part:

```
Gridview1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(Gridview1_Scroll);
```

to the form's constructor. Loops are unnecessary (the code does not depend on loop variables `_row` and `n`).

Also, in this part:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow _roww in Gridview2.Rows)
{
  for (int nn = 0; nn < Gridview2.Columns.Count; nn++)
  {
    Gridview2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Gridview1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
  }
}
```

loops are not needed. This part:

```
Gridview2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Gridview1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
```

will work by itself - note that it also does not depend on loop variables `_roww` and `nn`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! 
Now I have a lock button at the bottom of the form will allow the gridviews to scroll independently. It will be a toggle on, toggle off button to allow the user to see whether the scroll lock is engaged or not.